# Display applet version in Java Cache Viewer

Tags: java, caching, applet

Helllo,

When I open the Java Cache Viewer, see applets that were used. Some applets have shown the version number and some do not.

1. What is it specifically for the version number?
2. Where is this version number determined?
3. How do I set it to display the version number at my applet in Java Cache Viewer?

Thanks for answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved edit of JNLP file. I added `version` attribute in `jar` element.

Like this:

```
...
<resources>
   <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
   <jar href="/my-applet.jar" main="false" version="1.1.0"/>
</resources>
...
```